# IBMQProvider issue

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I successfully installed and ran a couple of circuits on a backend the other day (essex).
Everything was ok, results came up, but the next day, once I wanted more QC, I could not manage to get a provider.

I have looked into my account (active), looked into the package (up-to-date), and a new file in the project. I also already disabled and enabled the account without problems, but I keep having this error.

Code

```
from qiskit import IBMQ

IBMQ.active_account()

IBMQ.providers()

provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
```

and I get:

```
>~/my_environment_name/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqfactory.py in get_provider(self, hub, group, project)
    425             raise IBMQProviderError('No provider matches the specified criteria: '
    426                                     'hub = {}, group = {}, project = {}'
--> 427                                     .format(hub, group, project))
    428         if len(providers) > 1:
    429             raise IBMQProviderError('More than one provider matches the specified criteria.'
IBMQProviderError: 'No provider matches the specified criteria: hub = ibm-q, group = open, project = main'
```

I would like to know where I am wrong, I look forward to keep learning thru the backends efficiently.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no provider that matches all the criteria you specified, so in that hub, group and project. This could be because your account hasn't loaded correctly, so check to see if anything is returned from `IBMQ.providers()`. If there isn't anything load your account using `IBMQ.load_account()`. The other issue could be that there are genuinely no backends that meet those criteria, so try running `IBMQ.get_provider()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did try this. I got the following error:  
`
ibmqfactory.load_account:
Credentials are already in use. The existing account in the session will be replaced.
ibmqfactory._initialize_providers:
Unable to instantiate provider for {'hub': 'ibm-q', 'group': 'open', 'project': 'main'}: "{'online_date': ['Not a valid datetime.']}"
ibmqfactory.load_account:
No Hub/Group/Projects could be found for this account.
`
Still a bir confused, I had no problems yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use API token to enable your IBMQ account.

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.enable_account("your-api-key") # We load our account 
provider.backends() # We retrieve the backends to check their status

for b in provider.backends():
    print(b.status().to_dict())
```

Create IBM Quantum account if you don't have one, then use the API token that available in the dashboard as `enable_account()` method argument to resolve this issue.

For More: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/account/ibmq

https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/

https://www.ibm.com/account/reg/us-en/signup?formid=urx-19776&target=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.ibm.com%2Foidc%2Fendpoint%2Fdefault%2Fauthorize%3FqsId%3D70b061b4-7c64-4545-a504-a8871f2d414f%26client_id%3DN2UwMWNkYmMtZjc3YS00

[image: IDMQ Dashboard]